# Allday option in ionic calendar native

Tags: ionic-framework

I tried ionic-native-calendar to create an event in my local calendar app, but how do I add an 'allday' option in it ?

```
calendar.createEventWithOptions("Title","Location","Meeting",startdate,enddate,options)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find an answer using cordova plugin calendar i get the allday option to fulfill my requirement.

```
 var calOptions = (<any>window).plugins.calendar.getCalendarOptions();
 calOptions.allday = true;
   (<any>window).plugins.calendar.createEventWithOptions("Hello","","Meeting",start,enddate,calOptions)
```